# Using self join and left outer join on the same table?

Tags: join, sybase, sap-ase

Newbie with SQL development. I got this strange scenario  where I want to join 3 tables Table A,B,C. The use case is to return column X which is a primary key in table C. The column X is also a FK in table A and B.

Now I want to create a view by left joining all the 3 tables. The view has have 4 columns, A.id, B.id, C.A_X, C.B_X

The users can either use A.id or B.id to get the data. Now that's the scenario.

How should I join these tables so that I don't miss any values for C.X for every A.id and B.id.

```
Sample results:

A.id   B.id   C.A_X   C.B_X

1       null   ABC     null
null    2      null     XYZ
```

Cheers!!

Comment: I think sample data and desired results would help explain what you are doing.

Comment: Added a sample result set..